# OpenAM user account lock / unlock event handler

Tags: openam, opendj

We have a requirement to call a webservice and insert some values to oracle db after a user lock / user unlock happens in OpenAM.

How can we achieve this?

Is there any way to achieve this using any event handlers ?

Or

do we need to use openDJ Account Status Notification Handlers.
I have gone through the openDJ Account Status Notification Handlers and tried to create a Custom Account Status Notification Handler.

I create a new objectClass and create an new entry in config.ldiff file with java-class as my custom class which extends AccountStatusNotificationHandler, but when I starts openDJ it throws

**Exception**:

BootstrapData.startEmbeddedDS: 
org.opends.server.config.ConfigException: An error occurred while trying to decode the managed object configuration entry cn=Custom Notification Handler,cn=Account Status Notification Handlers,cn=config: The Account Status Notification Handler could not be decoded due to the following reason: The string value "org.opends.server.extensions.CustomAccountStatusNotificationHandler" is not a valid value for the "java-class" property, which must have the following syntax: CLASS <= org.opends.server.api.AccountStatusNotificationHandler (ServerManagementContext.java:839 ServerManagementContext.java:774 ServerManagementContext.java:467 ServerManagedObject.java:493 RootCfgDefn.java:2540 AccountStatusNotificationHandlerConfigManager.java:124 DirectoryServer.java:2904 DirectoryServer.java:1445 EmbeddedUtils.java:88 EmbeddedOpenDS.java:455 BootstrapData.java:230 BootstrapData.java:187 Bootstrap.java:178 Bootstrap.java:161 Bootstrap.java:145 AMSetupServlet.java:427 AMSetupServlet.java:202 StandardWrapper.java:1213 StandardWrapper.java:1026 StandardContext.java:4425 StandardContext.java:

OpenAM version is 11.0.0

My openAM server is apache tomcat.

Thanks

Abhilash KP

Answer (score 1):

If you use OpenAM lockout mechanism, then this won't set OpenDJ's account status, but sets a value to the configured account status attribute.

Currently OpenAM does not have any interface where you can plug into when and account is being locked.

So you have to use OpenDJ account lockout features ...

Comment: How can we add custom AccountStatusNotificationHandler in openDJ ?